# Is it possible to jump to HTML element by class instead of id?

Tags: javascript, html, class, anchor

I know that you can jump to elements by id but is it possible to jump to elements by class?

Am I going to have to use javascript to add an id to the element with that class name?

It would be a pain to add ids manually every time, the class names will already be there.

*I could have worded my question a bit better. I meant to use class names that are already there as anchor tags to jump to. The html I'm working with has class names for a LOT of individual elements and no ids. I'm wanting to jump to those elements without having to add an id to each and every one.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Did you check out my answer?

Comment: I would like to have a solution which allow me to use it in a url like actually it is possible with an id. In other words, a no javascript solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though i wouldn't recommend to use a class to jump to an element...

You can use this a couple of different jQuery such as **[ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)** or **[ScrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=CSS/scrollTop&redirect=no)**

Answer (score 5):

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector(".className").offsetTop);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/kEFp7/

Answer (score 5):

FYI: On chrome you can create an **anchor to a text**, which will take you to that section and also highlight the text.

The most common syntax is: `#:~:text=Some text`

And all possible usages are:
`#:~:text=[prefix-,]textStart[,textEnd][,-suffix]` which would allow you to select text **from , to** , **inclusive / exclusive**

Consider the following example links:

- Selecting text ["Private Address Space"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#:%7E:text=Private%20Address%20Space)
- Selecting text [from the word "advantage" up to word "space"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#:%7E:text=advantage,space)
- Selecting text [from the word "advantage" up to word "space" which has a word "by" after](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#:%7E:text=advantage,space,-by)
- Selecting the paragraph [between header titles "Introduction" and "2. Motivation"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#:%7E:text=Introduction-,For,.,-2.%20Motivation)

Specs: [W3C community draft report](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/#syntax)

Answer (score -3):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className')
```

or, using jQuery

```
$('.className')
```

Comment: The OP said `jump to`, not how to select them.